# laravel eloquent get all common chats between multiple users

Tags: php, laravel, eloquent

i was working on a chat project in laravel
i want to get all chats that multiple users are participating into together
i read the docs of where clauses but couldn't figure out any solution for this situation

i searched a lot to find any magical function that can do what i need but i couldn't find any help

#### Relations:

```
user --------- one to many ---> chat
recipient ---- one to one ----> user
chat --------- one to many ----> recipient
```

say i have a table like this

#### Recipients Table

```
|--------------|----------------|----------------|
|      id      |     user_id    |     chat_id    |
|--------------|----------------|----------------|
|      1       |        1       |        2       |
|      2       |        2       |        2       |
|      3       |        3       |        2       |
|      4       |        3       |        1       |
|      5       |        2       |        3       |
|      6       |        2       |        1       |
|--------------|----------------|----------------|
```

> i want to get the chat_id where users [1,2,3]
> and they must be participating in the same chat

i am expecting it to return 2

```
// i tried this snippet but it's only returning the chats of a single user 
$user_id = $request->user()['id'];
return Chat::whereHas('recipients', function ($query) use ($user_id) {
    $query->where('user_id', $user_id);
})->get();
```

Comment: what is the relation between chat and recipients?

Comment: chat --- one to many ---> recipient

Comment: i wanted to provide a pic of my DB schema but it's a little too messy with 15 tables all connecting to each others

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use `whereIn()` and specify the number of rows:

```
$user_ids = [1, 2, 3];

return Chat::has('recipients', '=', count($user_ids))
    ->whereHas('recipients', function ($query) use ($user_ids) {
        $query->whereIn('user_id', $user_ids);
    }, '=', count($user_ids))->get();
```

Comment: it's very close however when i pass [1, 3] it returns the chat with id 2 >> this should return null because there is no chat between 1 and 3 it's 1, 2 and 3 i though the check for the count might fix it as you did but it's not

Comment: yeah it worked thanks! can you explain why first answer wasn't working and why this is working i can't figure out much difference

Comment: The first query matched chats that contain *at least* the given users, but could also contain others. The new query only matches chats that *exactly* contain the given users.